# How to check if all rows validate a predicate

Tags: sql, oracle

I've a table in my database for which I need to check if all rows have one field not null.

If there are no row or if there is at least 1 row with the field null => true

If there are rows and they are all with the field not null => False

Is there a way to do this in on simple query? Or I need to check if my table is empty first then if it's not check if I've a row with the field value empty ?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Oracle but I'll need to translate this into predicate in the end anyway

Comment: "[Do] I need to check if my table is empty first[?]" - When a table is empty then all its constraints will be satisfied.

Comment: Checking if my table was empty first, would have made it so I only needed to check if there was at least one row with the value null afterward to know in which case I was. But the purpose of this question was to do it all in one query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `count(*)` and `count(field)` and compare the two:

```
select 
  case when count(*) > 0 and count(*) = count(field) then 1 -- not empty and no nulls
  else 0 end as isgood
from mytable;
```

Oracle SQL has no boolean data type , so I use 1 for true and 0 for false. You can replace this with whatever you like (e.g. 'true' instead of 1 and 'false' instead of 0).

As to turning this into a predicate (correlated to a main query), you'd use something along the lines of:

```
select ...
from main
where exists
(
  select 1
  from mytable
  where mytable.colx = main.coly
  having count(*) > 0 and count(*) = count(field)
);
```

Comment: Thank you for the query. I Meant java jpa criteria, but I should manage from there. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

This will count how many NULL values you have in a field;

```
SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN FieldName IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) NullValues
FROM TableName
```

Will return 0 if there are no NULL values, and will return the number of NULLS if there are any present.

If you actually want to return a value as 'True' or 'False' then do this;

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN a.NullValues > 0
            THEN 'True'
        ELSE 'False'
        END CheckField
FROM (
        SELECT 
        SUM(CASE WHEN FieldName IS NULL
                    THEN 1
                ELSE 0
                END) NullValues
        FROM TableName
    ) a
```

Comment: It's not exactly what I was looking for but at least your first query allows me to know the status in one query, if the result is 1 or null then it's the first case, if it's 0, it's the second case. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with aggregation.  However, it is difficult to understand what you are asking for.  If you want to check that a field has no `NULL` values, you can do:

```
select (case when count(*) > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as HasNullValues
from t
where field is null;
```

Comment: This returns 0 if all my rows have the field not null or if there are no row at all. What I need is to return 0 if there are rows and they all have field not null, and 1 otherwise.

Comment: @TheBakker . . . You mean you simply need to switch the "1" and the "0"?

Comment: No, your query returns the same result if all the rows have the field not null or if there are no rows at all. And another if there is at least one row with the field null. What I needed was all rows with value not null on one side, and no rows or at least 1 row with the value null on the other

Answer (score 0):

Alternate way I found using max with putting null first:

```
select case when 
    max(field) keep (dense_rank first order by datfin desc nulls first) is null then 1 
    else 0 end as flag 
from MYTABLE;
```